# Huge gap between TouchableOpacity after FlatList

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a TouchableOpacity after a FlatList in react native. Although it's coming under the view but there is a huge gap between the list and the button.[image]

Following is the corresponding code :

```
           <FlatList keyExtractor={(payment) => payment.iconFont} style={{ alignSelf: "center" }} data={payments} renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return <View style={{ width: '100%', marginTop: 32 }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <View>
                            <FontAwesome5 name={item.iconFont} size={32} />
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 16 }}>{item.mainText}</Text>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 12 }}>{item.SubText}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            }} />

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500", fontSize: 20 }}>PAY</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

I am doing something wrong over here ?

P.S. => Although `FlatList` is working fine

the corresponding styles :

```
button: {
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        height: 40,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderRadius: 20
    }
```

Comment: The text of your touchable opacity is white. If you haven't changed the background color you won't see it.

Comment: Actually that's not the problem. I have provided the style : 
button: {
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        height: 40,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderRadius: 20
    }

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in that case. Can you show more of the layout or share a snack?

Comment: I have updated the qs accordingly

Comment: can you show the container View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the Touchable Opacity into Flatlist's listfootercomponent prop. Like this:

```
<FlatList
     ListFooterComponent={<TouchableOpacity> .... </TouchableOpacity>}
/>
```

This should solve the spacing problem. And place the TouchableOpacity component always at the bottom of the FlatList.